# We have an offline network with a repo/mirror on it. but I can't figure out how to add it to my sources.list correctly

Tags: 16.04, apt, repository

I have been reading tutorials on how to setup local network repos. But this is not quite what I have - in my case there is a network repo already existing - lets say it lives here:

`http://netpc/repos/`

Inside the folder structure looks like (I have only expanded this a little bit, but there is loads of folders / sub-folders that all look very Ubuntu-y):

```
/1604/
/1604/mirror
/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com
/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/mwg-internal
/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
/1604/skel
/1604/var
...etc...
```

So following what I have read I think I just need to update my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. I have made a backup, then I added the following to the file:

```
# Adding local network repo
deb http://netpc/repos ./
```

Then I did the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got the following output (hand-typed cuz its on a different PC offline):

```
Ign:1 http://netpc/repos/1604/ ./ InRelease
Ign:2 http://netpc/repos/1604/ ./ Release
Ign:3 http://netpc/repos/1604/ ./ Packges
Ign:4 http://netpc/repos/1604/ ./ Translation-en_GB
Ign:5 http://netpc/repos/1604/ ./ Translation-en
Ign:3 http://netpc/repos/1604/ ./ Packages
         :
         :
Ign:5 http://netpc/repos/1604/ ./ Translation-en
Err:3 http://netpc/repos/1604/ ./ Packages
    404 Not Found
Ign:4 http://netpc/repos/1604/ ./ Translation-en_GB
Ign:5 http://netpc/repos/1604/ ./ Translation-en
         :
         :
W: the repository 'http://netpc/repos/1604 ./ Release' does not have a release file.
         :
         :
E: Failed to fetch http://netpc/repos/1604/./Packages   404  Not Found
```

It tries to connect to the other repos on the web (but we are not connected to the web) so it can't find places like gb.archive.ubuntu.com...

So I want my system to ignore on-line locations and just use my one "mirror" location on our LAN.

- Why is my setup not working (what did I miss)?
- What steps do I need to take to solve this and to ignore other internet-based locations?

**UPDATE**

I have updating sources.list from the two answers - I tried the following with better results:

```
# Main and restricted
deb http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb-src http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted

# Universe
    :
# Multiverse
    :
```

and re-ran `sudo apt-get update`

So I can't type out all of the output, but I've put the main errors at the end of the process here:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found 
E: Failed to fetch http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found 
E: Failed to fetch http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found
```

So it looks like it can't find i386 stuff (32-bit) which I am not sure I care about because I am using 64-bit... I think...

Comment: Please edit your question and add in specifics on the error you got. Otherwise we're just guessing.  It would also help if you added your complete sources.list

Comment: @OrganicMarble sorry - have to hand-type it : ( ... added the main errors. It is making some progress now (I can see the percentage going up and a load of gets).

Comment: You are probably right about the 32 bit archives. I had to go back in and add them to my local mirror.  If you don't need them, you can add `[arch=amd64]` after the word `deb` in your sources.list and you won't get this error.  The lines would look like `deb [arch=amd64]  http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted`

Comment: @OrganicMarble yeah - that got it : )  ... I have further issues with versions/broken-packages (my test is to install vim i.e. `sudo apt-get install vim`) but I think that is for another questions. Thanks : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I have set up my own local mirror and got it to work.

I'm suspicious of the `./` in the line you added to sources.list.  Mine looks like this:

```
# updated for local mirror on 2/11/18

# local main & restricted sources

deb ssh://my-server/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb ssh://my-server/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb ssh://my-server/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted

# local universe sources

deb ssh://my-server/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb ssh://my-server/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb ssh://my-server/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe

# local multiverse sources

deb ssh://my-server/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb ssh://my-server/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb ssh://my-server/apt-mirror/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
```

I use ssh instead of http, but that is not the difference I am trying to point out.

I think you need to edit your sources.list and add the proper text after the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding the base URL of your LAN repository is not enough. You need to direct `apt` to the relevant parts of the repository structure, including which version of Ubuntu you're using (by release name).

Replace the base URL in each line of your sources file, but keep the rest of the information on that line.

If you're using 14.04, Trusty Tahr, your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file looks something like this:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
...
```

Your updated file should look more like:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://netpc/repos/1604/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
...
```